# How to configure nginx to store access logs by minute?

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to configure nginx to create a new access log for a given host per minute?

An external process/application will be reading from these log files, and I want to make sure there are no file locking issues etc., so if I can have nginx create a new log file every minute, this way I can make sure I don't touch the current minutes log file.

Comment: FYI there are no issues with locking when one process is reading and another process is writing the file. In my setup I have a perl script which continually reads the nginx logs and spits out per minute stats, and the log file are rotated every 24 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Just going to [quote from the developer](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/73) here:

> If you really want logging to an external process - try using mkfifo(1), but please keep in mind that this will lead to service interruption if your logging process won't be able to cope with load. I would recommend logging to a normal file and using "tail -F /path/to/log | script" instead if you need some log processing.

See also: [Proper way to rotate Nginx logs](https://serverfault.com/q/65118/126632)

Answer (score 0):

[Nginx official documentation: Rotating Log-files](http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html#logs)

Comment: Thanks, but how do you "After that USR1 signal should be sent to the master process." ?

Comment: See `man kill` - one of the most basic unix/linux commands.

Comment: Also `nginx -s reopen` (see `man nginx`)

Comment: so they are suggesting to actually shutdown the nginx server, so the site will be down for a split second during this log rotating process?

Comment: so is it saying to 1) rename the file 2) shutdown nginx 3) start it again, and it will create new files?

Comment: You don't need to shutdown nginx, just send `USR1` signal.